# Share folder between users without making it visible to a network

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, sharing

I want two user accounts of my Windows 10 PC to have full access to a particular folder and its subfolders and files.

So, I right clicked over the folder from UserX account and went to *Give Access To* and then, below, I clicked over UserY which I want to share the folder with.

[image]

Then, below, I chose *Yes share the items* option:
[image]

Then, I am asked if I want to turn on public network sharing or just private. I don't want to turn any network sharing at all.

[image]

So, even if I choose the "No" option above, the folder will still be shared with other computers when I connect to a private Wireless network. I don't want this folder to show even on private networks. With this setup, I can access the folder from my other PC (from *Network*) connected to the same wireless network.

Is there a way to share a folder between users of the same PC without making it visible over a wireless network?

Comment: File and Folder Sharing is a general option which must be ON for any sharing to happen. Beyond this, you control who has access by the user name (and password). It may be visible to other users but not accessible if no permission. Private Network connection is necessary for sharing. Public Network precludes most sharing

Comment: @John but what defines a "Public" and a "Private" network? I often work in cafes and I am connected to their password-protected wireless network. That's a private network, but others are also connected and can see my computer. Yes, they don't have my user account username/password to be able to see my files, but that doesn't sound very secure still.

Comment: Public Network setting stops sharing and is used in locations that are unsafe

Comment: If you have a single Windows 10 PC, don't share anything over the network, just set permissions on the folder.

Comment: @multigoodverse, a cafe is the definition of a public network, a network where there are other machines that are not controlled by you/family/company. Not machines you want to share files or printers with.
In contrast to a private network, where the other machines are (somewhat) trusted, and you DO want to share (some of) your and the other machines data and printers for instance. Your company network is a private network, not a public.
Private=trusted, public= untrusted. Treat every network as public unless you need to share your or other machines data/devices.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do isn't sharing - the term 'sharing' is only used for between multiple PCs, not two users of the same PC.

What you should do instead, is go into the folder properties and select the **Security** tab

change the permissions by clicking **Edit**

click **Add...** and on the pop-up enter the name of the user you want to give access to.

Then select the new user in the list, and tick the allow box for the permissions you want to give them. Most of the time you'll want to just give them **Modify** permissions - this gives them all they'll need to read, change and run any files in the folder.

(tested all this on windows 10 pro)